# Return array from class in Java

Tags: java, arrays

The array that returns from method contain undesirable values. I don't know why.

This is DriverExam Class:

```
public class DriverExam 
{

    private char[] answer = {'B','D','A','A','C','A','B','A','C','D',
                             'B','C','D','A','D','C','C','B','D','A'};
    private char[] stuAnswer = new char[20];
    private int totalCorrect = 0;
    private int[] missed = new int[20];

    public DriverExam(char stuAnswer[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stuAnswer.length; i++)
        {
            this.stuAnswer[i] = stuAnswer[i];
        }
    }

    public int gettotalCorrect()
    {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < stuAnswer.length; i++)
        {
            if (stuAnswer[i] == answer[i])
                totalCorrect++;
        }
        return totalCorrect;
    }

    public int gettotalIncorrect()
    {
        return 20-totalCorrect;
    }

    public int[] getMissed()
    {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < stuAnswer.length; i++)
        {
            if (stuAnswer[i] != answer[i])
            {
                missed[k] = i;
                k++;
            }
        }
        return missed;
    }
}
```

This is the main program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main6 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        char[] answer = new char[20];
        int[] missed2;
        String str;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the answer for question #"+i);
            str = keyboard.nextLine();

            while (Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) != 'A' 
                    && Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) != 'B'
                    && Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) != 'C'
                    && Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) != 'D')
            {
                System.out.println("Your input is invalid. Only accept A, B, C, or D");
                System.out.println("Enter the answer for question #"+i);
                str = keyboard.nextLine();
            }

            answer[i-1] = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0));
        }

        DriverExam de = new DriverExam (answer);

        System.out.print("***FINAL RESULT:");
        System.out.print("\nTotal correct answers: "+de.gettotalCorrect());
        System.out.print("\nTotal incorrect answers: "+de.gettotalIncorrect());
        System.out.print("\nQuestions missed: ");

        missed2 = de.getMissed();
        for (int i = 0; i < missed.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

In DriverExam class I return an array named "missed" to the main program. In main program, I use an array named "missed2" to store the array returned. But when I print the result (I type all the answer with "A"). It's like below:

> FINAL RESULT:
>   Total correct answers: 6
>   Total incorrect answers: 14
>   Questions missed: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

The question missed result is strange and incorrect.

Comment: I don't see how that last loop even compiles, since `missed` isn't declared in that scope.  Either way, this looks like a good opportunity for you to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.

Comment: @David `missed` is a field in the `DriverExam` class to which the method belongs.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Right, which is out of scope in the `main()` method in the `Main6` class.

Comment: When you're printing, you print the *index* (`i`), rather than the content of `missed`. I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Well, there's more to it than that typo.  Because the "questions missed" is still iterating 20 times, when it should iterate only 14 times according to the intended result.  However, since the code given doesn't even compile, it's really anybody's guess what the *actual* code looks like which produces this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want for "missed" to be is a variable length result.  To do this with an array, you will need a value that signals the end of the results.  Here, I've used -1.

```
public int[] getMissed()
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stuAnswer.length; i++)
    {
        if (stuAnswer[i] != answer[i])
        {
            missed[k] = i;
            k++;
        }
    }
    if(k < missed.length)
    {
      missed[k] = -1
    }
    return missed;
}
```

Then, in your for loop, check for the end value.  The strange values are probably default int values caused by not setting them explicitly in the array.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < missed2.length && missed2[i] != -1; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
```

Comment: Additionally, as noted in comments above, the output should print the contents of `missed2` (not `missed`) instead of the index of `i`.